# Sqlserver existing user give 'db_owner' to a db is failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a user created in sqlserver -> security -> Logins
I would like to provide the db owner role to the existing user to a database.
When i try change the user properties in SSMS, i get the following error:

[image]

The user already exists. I only want to update the owner property.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual SQL you are running here?

Comment: i am using sqlserver 2014. i am doing this from management studio. The user in the respective database has got mapped to multiple schemas.

Comment: Yes, but what you are doing is running SQL, what is that SQL? Clearly you are trying to create a `USER` that already exists, hence the error.

Comment: I resoted the db which has already got the user in individual db. thats the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Because the user already exists in individual db, update the db owner can't be done until the user is dropped.

so i dropped the user by droppping the owned schema first and then dropped the user

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19456/the-database-principal-owns-a-schema-in-the-database-and-cannot-be-dropped-mess/19458